# debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, dpkg

I was running the command `sudo apt install mongodb-org`. And I got these errors.

```
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 31%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 63%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 94%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such 
file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Output of `ls -ls /var/lib/dpkg/info/{,format-new} | head -n2`

```
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg/info/': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such file or directory
```

Output of `apt-cache policy debconf`

```
debconf:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.73
  Version table:
     1.5.73 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `ls -ls /var/lib/dpkg/info/{,format-new} | head -n2` and `apt-cache policy debconf` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I have added the outputs. Please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have severe damage of your system. Below is the possible way to fix this situation on low level:

```
# create missed dpkg info directory
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info/

# create missed dpkg alternatives directory
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives

# recreate other directories as well
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/{parts,triggers,updates}

# update package lists
sudo apt-get update

# install missed debconf package
sudo apt-get install debconf

# reinstall all currently installed packages to correctly fill /var/lib/dpkg/info/
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
```

And finally install whatever packages with commands like:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Comment: while doing these process, I got new error   -    update-alternatives: error: cannot scan directory '/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives': No such file or directory

Comment: Then run `sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives` and repeat steps in answer.

Comment: Finally, it worked. Thankyou so much Sir :)